# SVN Checkout of multi module maven project causing build issues

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-3, multi-module

I am trying to learn how to setup multi-module maven project and share it with colleagues using SVN.

We work with eclipse IDE.

Here is how my project structure looks in SVN.
[image]

Each module has its own svn labels and tag trunk, branches, tags etc.

I check out all the modules individually by right clicking on them and choosing check out.

Finally I get the below in my eclipse project explorer:

[image]

Here is my pom for the parent project. and this throws errors when I do a mvn clean install
[image]

I want to understand how to checkout the projects/ modify my pom to get the build successful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to check out the root folders of your modules in SVN. All you want is the content of the trunk. So right click on the trunk folder and select `Check out as...`. Check it out as new projects and enable Maven on those project afterwards. Do this with each of your modules and you should be fine.

If you have Maven SVN connectors installed you have an option called `Check out as Maven project`. This is very comfortable as it does a few steps for you.

Comment: This works fine.. Thank you.. Would like to know if this is the right way of doing it? I mean the widely accepted way of doing it.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with that way. The alternative woudl be having all modules in the same trunk. This way you could check them out all at once and with the SVN connectores Maven does it's magic. But you loose the ability to versionate your modules seperately.